# Problem with date matching between a variable and a date column Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

The problem is that this query is working fine:

```
CREATE TABLE PROCESGEN_TEST
(PROCESENDTIME TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO PROCESGEN_TEST
(SELECT DISTINCT PROCESENDTIME FROM  dwh_procesgeneriek@xob10
WHERE PROCESENDTIME IS NOT NULL
AND PROCESENDTIME > '10-09-2020 01:00:00');

Def TIME2 = (SELECT MAX_EXEC_TIME FROM EXEC_TIME);
SELECT PROCESENDTIME  
FROM PROCESGEN_TEST
WHERE PROCESENDTIME < &TIME2
AND PROCESEINDTIJD IS NOT NULL
```

In the above situation we first put the data into a table created in de database management system we use (named xor01 and not the xob10). In the query beneath we extract the data directly from xob10. This isn’t working when we want to select a date (greater or lower then..) and we don’t know why.

```
CREATE TABLE EXEC_TIME
(MAX_EXEC_TIME DATE);

INSERT INTO EXEC_TIME
(
  SELECT TO_DATE(
           TO_CHAR(
             MAX(EXEC_DATE),
             'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
           ),
           'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
         ) - 1.1666
  from   L3DD_MIN_ACTIVITIES_BRD_BAK_Will
);

Def TIME3 = (SELECT MAX_EXEC_TIME FROM EXEC_TIME);

SELECT PROCESENDTIME
FROM   dwh_procesgeneriek@xob10 
WHERE  PROCESENDTIME IS NOT NULL
AND    TO_DATE(PROCESENDTIME,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')
         > TO_DATE(&TIME3, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS');
```

The problem is that the query is not finding a single date in the last query and keeps on executing. If we replace `TO_DATE(&TIME3, 'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS')` with a certain date like `'10-08-2020 20:00:00'` the query will find the right dates. We have tried all kinds of things, like working with `TIMESTAMP` format and `TO_TIMESTAMP`. Nothing works. It looks like a rather simple problem.

Does anyone know what’s causing the problem the query can’t find any dates in the second query?

Comment: What tool do you use for that? Is it sqlplus?

Comment: Why are you using `to_date()` on values which are *already* dates? (Also don't use YY; use YYYY or if you really have to deal with 2-digit years, you should usually use RR). Your insert doesn't look right either.

Comment: Is this your full script? What happens when you replace `&TIME3` with `(SELECT MAX_EXEC_TIME FROM EXEC_TIME)`? Assuming this is just an SQL Plus/Developer substitution variable, I think that's what your tool is doing anyway.

Comment: I am working with Benthic Golden 7 software. I tried the suggestions but no results. The source of the problem is that the data is coming form an other Oracle (I think) database. Golden is recently upgraded to version 7. Maybe there is a mismatch in the NLS Parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need:

- the `EXEC_TIME` table;
- to convert a timestamp to a string and then back to a date;
- to use a variable; or
- to filter on `PROCESENDTIME IS NOT NULL` (since the `>` filter only works on non-`NULL` values).

Then you can use:

```sql
SELECT PROCESENDTIME
FROM   dwh_procesgeneriek@xob10 
WHERE  PROCESENDTIME
         > (
             SELECT MAX(EXEC_DATE) - INTERVAL '1 4' DAY TO HOUR
             FROM   L3DD_MIN_ACTIVITIES_BRD_BAK_Will
           );
```

If you do want the `EXEC_TIME` table then:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EXEC_TIME( MAX_EXEC_TIME DATE );

INSERT INTO EXEC_TIME
SELECT MAX(EXEC_DATE) - INTERVAL '1 4' DAY TO HOUR
FROM   L3DD_MIN_ACTIVITIES_BRD_BAK_Will;

SELECT PROCESENDTIME
FROM   dwh_procesgeneriek@xob10 
WHERE  PROCESENDTIME > ( SELECT MAX_EXEC_TIME FROM EXEC_TIME );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. I tried the first query but stil no result. If I replace 
             SELECT MAX(EXEC_DATE) - INTERVAL '1 4' DAY TO HOUR
             FROM   L3DD_MIN_ACTIVITIES_BRD_BAK_Will
           ) in the first query with the real date time in MAX(EXEC_DATE) , this is '19-09-2020 20:00:00'. Then it will give the right results. An example of a date in PROCESENDTIME is '17-07-2015 15:42:06'. So they have both the same format. I am working here with Benthic Golden 7 software. Maybe I am overlooking something here,but I don't know what.